# How to right-align a Bootstrap element? Is there a universal way to do it? Why doesn't d-flex + ml-auto always work?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have trouble right-aligning a button. I know, it sounds pretty basic (and it is), but I noticed some inconsistencies that make it a bit of a challenge for me. These inconsistencies include:

- `d-flex ml-auto` helps with `input` buttons but doesn't help with `a` buttons (they spread)
- that is, unless you add a `max-content` `style` attribute, `style="width:max-content"` – then it works as well
- or unless its parent element is a `.row`

I have these questions in mind:

1. Why??
2. Is there a universal way to right-align a Bootstrap element *without modifying its parent element* (I don't necessarily want to right-align everything in the containing element) *or using inline style* (I don't think it's professional)
3. In particular, **how do I right-align an `a.btn` inside a `modal-body`** (preferably, with the requirements in italics being met)?

`.modal-body` doesn't seem to have much to do with it, though, as you can see on this screenshot

[image]

If you feel like closing it for not being focused, **please ignore anything except for the question in bold** (or tell me to move other questions in the comments)

Also, keep in mind that I examined [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=right-align%20bootstrap) search results. They don't appear helpful

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mw-100">

     <p class="text-center">&lt;input type="submit" class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong>"&gt; inside a div.modal-body:</p>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" href="#" value="I am a right-aligned button"></a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-center">&lt;a class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong>"&gt; inside a div.modal-body:</p>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <a class="btn btn-danger d-flex ml-auto" href="#">I am_<strong>not</strong>_a right-aligned button</a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-center">&lt;a class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong> style="width:max-content""&gt; inside a div.modal-body:</p>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <a class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" style="width:max-content" href="#">I am a right-aligned button</a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-center">&lt;a class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong>"&gt; inside a regular div:</p>
     <div class="mb-2">
        <a class="btn btn-danger d-flex ml-auto" href="#">I am_<strong>not</strong>_a right-aligned button</a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-center">&lt;a class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong>"&gt; inside a div.row:</p>
     <div class="row">
        <a class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" href="#">I am a right-aligned button</a>
     </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is way in bootstrap to right-align an a.btn inside a modal-body without without modifying its parent element or using inline style, and that's to use `d-table` instead of `d-flex`.

In general, you want an element that's shrink-to-fit, so that the unused horizontal space can be used by the `ml-auto` (`margin-left: auto`) Inline-level elements do that, but you don't want to use them; floats do, but you'd them have to change following elements so they weren't positioned alongside the float; absolute positioned elements do that but you'd them have to change following elements so they didn't overlay the abspos'd element; elements with `width:(min/max/fit)-content` do that, but bootstrap doesn't provide any classes for that; and tables do that, which meets all your stated requirements.

Having said that, I don't think it's a good solution. If I used bootstrap (I don't), I'd probably be augmenting the bootstrap classes with something like a `w-shrink-to-fit` class set to `width:fit-content` and then follow your second bullet point.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mw-100">

     <p class="text-center">&lt;input type="submit" class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong>"&gt; inside a div.modal-body:</p>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" href="#" value="I am a right-aligned button"></a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-center">&lt;a class="btn <strong>d-table ml-auto</strong>"&gt; inside a div.modal-body:</p>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <a class="btn btn-danger d-table ml-auto" href="#">I am a right-aligned button now</a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-center">&lt;a class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong> style="width:max-content""&gt; inside a div.modal-body:</p>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <a class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" style="width:max-content" href="#">I am a right-aligned button</a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-center">&lt;a class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong>"&gt; inside a regular div:</p>
     <div class="mb-2">
        <a class="btn btn-danger d-flex ml-auto" href="#">I am_<strong>not</strong>_a right-aligned button</a>
     </div>

     <p class="text-center">&lt;a class="btn <strong>d-flex ml-auto</strong>"&gt; inside a div.row:</p>
     <div class="row">
        <a class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" href="#">I am a right-aligned button</a>
     </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```